# Not able to fetch the item level rating for the document programatically in sharepoint 2013

Tags: user-profile-service, rating, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get the current logged in user rating for items in document libraries . However. It is giving rating as 0 for the all the documents. I am using below code

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
        {
                    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                    {

  string fileUri = "http://..." + webUrlSplit;

  Uri urifileUrl = new Uri(fileUri);

   SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);

   SocialRatingManager mySocialRatingManager = new SocialRatingManager(context);

   SocialRating aRating = mySocialRatingManager.GetRating(urifileUrl);

    string myRating = aRating.Url + ": " + aRating.Rating;                       

    objtopRated.myRating = myRating;

}

}
```

In the above code fileUri is the docuemnt url of the item in doc library

eg. `someSiteUrl/ProductsandPricing/Pricing/Pricing_Document 1.xlsx`

I referred the below msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407954.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[SocialRatingManager.GetRating method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee583363.aspx) accepts **absolute** URL as a parameter

```
public SocialRating GetRating(
    Uri url
)
```

To construct Uri for the List Item the following code could be used:

```
var itemUrl = new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, item.Url));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer...However,currently I am passing absolute ur only like     http:// sp2013/ProductsandPricing/Pricing/Pricing_Document 1.xlsx